# select onChange not working inside a form

Tags: javascript, forms, select, html-select, onchange

I have a question about form submit & onchange events not working together.  When I change the value on the dropdown list the event viewroom() is not firing.  Could anyone help me with this?  The code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewroom()
{
    alert(123);
}
</script>

<form id="myform" name="myform" action="joinroom.php" method="post">
<select name="viewroom" id="viewroom" onChange="viewroom()">
    <option value="1">Room1 </option>
    <option value="2">Room2 </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="Join room"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your function name conflicts with `name` and `id` of the `select`, just give another name to the function.

Comment: Also interestingly, if I move the select statements outside of the form, then the onChange event works without a problem.  (is this normal or just I get lucky?)

Comment: Unfortenately I don't know, the code seems to work exactly you desrcibed.

Comment: This wasn't exactly my issue, but I did have a naming conflict. Points for steering me in a good direction. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't name a function the same as an element on your page. I suggest changing the function name to something like `viewroomSelected` as shown [here in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/v5XFN/1/).

Relevant changes:

```
function viewroomSelected()
{
  alert(123);
}

<select name="viewroom" id="viewroom" onChange="viewroomSelected()">
```

Comment: interesting restriction! thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found that as you set `name` and `id` attribute same of your function name causing this conflict and prompting error `viewroom` is not a function, change the name of function. also define your js at the bottom of document.

```
function viewRoom()
{
    alert(123);
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8T8pf/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<select name="viewroom" id="viewroom" onChange="viewroom()">
```

to

```
<select name="viewroom" id="viewroom" onChange="()=>viewroom()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring some tip, **not for this case**, someone may have added a new and different function that killed the old one.

```
<select ... onchange="anOldFuncion()">
```

And in javascript later you did:

```
selectX.onchange = function(){};  //bye bye function from the tag.
```

The naming in this code is terrible. I would have choosen:

```
<select name="viewroom" id="viewroom" onChange="selectRoom()">
```