# Populating a text box based on a selection from a drop down

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate a text box based on the select box selection.

I have sample code (please see below) and the issue is : If I comment the `<form>` tag , the code below is working and if I uncomment the `<form>` tag  it is not working...could you please see the code below what I am doing wrong

P.S: I need to have a form since I have many other form fields like text boxes and select drop downs and I just need to populate a text box for one select.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
      <script type="text/javascript">      
      function test() {
          var select = document.getElementById("select");
          var texts = document.getElementById("texts");

          var val = select.options.value;
          texts.innerHTML = "";
          if (select.options.value == 2) {
              texts.innerHTML += 'Year:</td><div><td><input type="text" name="test" value="" /></div>';
          }   
      }
      </script>

      <body>
<!---      <form name="myform">--->
      <select id="select" size="1" onChange="JavaScript:test();" name ="test">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>

      <hr/>
            <tr><td>
            <div id="texts"></div>
            </td></tr>
<!---            </form>--->
      </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the `tr` tag you have in there? I don't see any table... maybe that's part of the problem. So first thing to try is: delete `<tr><td>` and `</td></tr>`, that's incorrect html

Comment: You don't need `Javascript:` in the `onchange` attribute. That's only needed when you put JS in `href`.

Comment: You can't start the `innerHTML` with `</td>`. DOM elements have to be properly nested, you can't close a `TD` that was started outside the element.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respone.

The reason I have added <tr> and <td> because I need to populate the text box in a specific place, otherwise the text box is populating on top of the page and I do have proper table and <tr> and <td> tags in my big form.
The code I have posted with innerhtml is working as I wanted and when I add the form tag it is not populating the text box at all.
Any other suggestions would be very very helpful

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919922/select-onchange-not-working-inside-a-form your issue is because the function and select have the same name. change your function name to anything else and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The core of the issue is explained at [select onChange not working inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919922/select-onchange-not-working-inside-a-form).

To explain why the name of an element takes precedence over the function name when inside a form due to scoping. It is standard to provide access to form elements via their name as part of the form object.

For instance in the example given you could access the select by the property `window.myform.test` because the select is inside the form when the `onchange` is parsed it looks at the local `myform` scope to find the select named `test` before the window scope where the function `test` is declared.

Without the form `test` is only declared in the window scope as a function.